# EntityManager giving NullPointerException in Junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, entitymanager

I have a repository implementation class inside `src/main/java` as below:

```
package com.test.repo.impl;

@Repository
class TestRepoImpl implements TestRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<SomeEntity> getSomeEntity() {
      //some logic
      //getting npe while testing
      return entityManger.createQuery(query, SomeEntity.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

This method is working fine. But when I'm trying to test it using Junit, it's giving me `NullPointerException` because `entityManager` is null.

I'm using MSSQL for actual implementation and in-memory H2 database.
I have create my test class inside `src/test/java` as below:

```
package com.test.repo.impl;

@DataJpaTest
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestRepoImplTest {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  //autowired some JPA entity to insert dummy data

  @BeforeAll
  public void init() {
     //dummy data insertion
  }

  @Test
  public void getSomeEntityTest() {
    TestRepo repo = new TestRepoImpl();
    repo.testSomeEntity(); 
    //some assertions
  }  

}
```

My question is how to initialize entityManager present in `TestRepoImpl` class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring will never inject anything in objects that you create yourself with `new`. It doesn't even know those objects exist. Use constructor injection and pass the EntityManager as argument. Or Autowire the TestRepo bean in your test.